# Mysql left join doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to join two tables.  The first table contains employee information such as employee number name etc.  The second table contains time clock information such as employee number, status(clocked in or out), datetime row was last updated, time clocked in, time clocked out, hours for the day.

I have something like this but real info in database

```
employees_tbl(
   employee_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   employee_first VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   employee_last VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( employee_id )
);
insert into employee (employee_id, employee_first, employee_last) values (1, First, Name);
insert into employee (employee_id, employee_first, employee_last) values (2, Second, Name);
insert into employee (employee_id, employee_first, employee_last) values (3, Third, Name);
insert into employee (employee_id, employee_first, employee_last) values (4, Fourth, Name);
insert into employee (employee_id, employee_first, employee_last) values (5, Fifth, Name);

employee number, status(clocked in or out), datetime row was last updated, time clocked in, time clocked out, hours
transactions_tbl(
   employee_id INT NOT NULL
   status VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
   datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
   clockin TIME,
   clockout TIME,
   hours TIME,
   PRIMARY KEY ( employee_id )
);

INSERT INTO transactions (employee_id, status, datetime, clockin, clockout, hours) VALUES (1, "OUT", "2015-08-10 05:00:00", "2015-08-10 04:00:00", "2015-08-10 05:00:00", "01:00:00");
INSERT INTO transactions (employee_id, status, datetime, clockin, clockout, hours) VALUES (2, "IN", "2015-08-11 05:00:00", "2015-08-11 04:00:00", , );
INSERT INTO transactions (employee_id, status, datetime, clockin, clockout, hours) VALUES (3, "IN", "2015-08-11 05:00:00", "2015-08-10 04:00:00", "2015-08-10 05:00:00", "01:00:00");
```

The output I am looking for is every employee should have their First Name and if they have Clocked in or out for the day the information should be displayed.  If they haven't clocked in or out for the day it should just show the last time they did clock in or out. It should always show the last record for the employee meaning the most recent activity. If they have never clocked in or out it should still display their name.

The query I am using is:

```
'SELECT employee_id, employee_first FROM employees e left join (SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY datetime DESC) as t1 on e.employee_id = t1.employee_id GROUP BY t1.employee_id'
```

however it is only giving me the first 3 employees and nothing for employee 4 and beyond.

I am coding this in mysql and php.  I would show the results as a table here but can't quite figure out how to make the table format properly.  Everything just jams up in a big mess that I can't even decifer. But hopefully you get the point.

Comment: Why do you have a derived table? It doesn't seem to serve a purpose in your query.

Comment: I was unable to limit the transactions table to only the most recent transaction for each employee with just the single query.  It should have worked fine but I kept getting told my grouping by employee_id was invalid.  So I tried doing it this way and it worked except it only outputs the first 3 employees(I have 15 in the actual table).

Comment: Have you tried to change `GROUP BY t1.employee_id` to `GROUP BY e.employee_id` ?

Comment: Grrrr!!  Thank you.  I knew I needed a second set of eyes.  Been staring at this for way too many hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_first
FROM employees e left join
     (SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY datetime DESC) as t1
     on e.employee_id = t1.employee_id
GROUP BY t1.employee_id;
```

It has several major errors.  The first is the use of `t1.employee_id` in the `GROUP BY`.  This is from the *second* table and not the first, so it could be `NULL`.  Second, you have an `ORDER BY` in the subquery, apparently expecting that to do something.  I also assume that you do want columns from `t1`.

Based on what you describe, I think you want:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_first, t.*
FROM employees e left join
     (SELECT employee_id, MAX(datetime) as maxdt
      FROM transactions 
      GROUP BY employee_id
     ) tmax
     on e.employee_id = tmax.employee_id left join
     transactions t
     on tmax.employee_id = t.employee_id and tmax.maxdt = t.datetime;
```

Comment: This is also what I envision the OP was looking for. An important thing to note is the use of two joins, one to make use of the aggregate `max` function then join the transactions again to actually grab the data you'll need.

Comment: MAX(datetime) was the way I was originally going with this but I couldn't get it to work.  The above suggestion give me the error Unknown column 'tmax.datetime' in 'on clause'  I changed "and tmax.datetime = t.datetime;" to "and tmax.maxdt = t.datetime;" and it worked.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a left join starting with the Transactions table. It only has 3 employees in it. Your code is working correctly. If you want to get all employees, do a right join on the transaction table.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
SELECT employee_id, employee_first
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN transactions t1 on e.employee_id = t1.employee_id
GROUP BY t1.employee_id
```

Oh, BTW, the reason why you are only getting 3 results and not 5 is because you are doing a `GROUP BY` on the `employee_id` of `t1` the transaction table. If you remove that or change it to `e.employee_id`, it should return the values you need.

Comment: Because if an employee clock in then clocks out for say a break or lunch and then clocks in again there is no guarantee when they go to clock in again that the query will choose the correct record.  Which would cause a lot of problems if it chooses the record where they are already clocked out and they are trying to clock out again.